# Sending .ics to gmail does not show the details in the invitation

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-calendar-api

I am sending invitations to gmail with an attachment of .ics file in my project using C#.

.ics file contains PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN

and sending this as "text/calendar", method=request.

**Problem that i am facing is**
When i view this in the gmail, i am not able to see the full description in the gmail. i need to click on more details button to see the full invitation details.
Please find the screen shot http://screencast.com/t/vl1egcf77ke

But if i send an invitation from google calender to another contact, i am able to see all the details below
http://screencast.com/t/6PgPdomt3F

**What needs to be fixed?**
Need to see the description in the email that i am sending.

Let me know if you need any more information regarding the same.